# Invalid tag name when setting up local HTTP server in the terminal using Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal

I am trying to Setup a Simple HTTP Server on my Mac. I have downloaded the NodeJS from https://nodejs.org. However, when I typed the following command in the terminal:

```
npm install npm –g
```

It showed me the following errors:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "–g": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/b.w.h/.npm/_logs/2020-07-23T03_48_48_744Z-debug.log
MacBook-Pro:react excercise b.w.h$
```

I have changed a few different directories that contain HTML and js files, but it still doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Why are you trying to install ``npm`` again?

Comment: Your `–g` option is using an _[ndash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm)_. Use a _[hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm)_ instead, e.g. `-g`. However as @Take-Some-Bytes has already said, it's probably not necessary to install `npm` again

Comment: Thanks, @Robc and @Take-Some-Bytes. But when I tried to run `http-server` in that directory, it returns `-bash: http-server: command not found`.

Comment: This is a different issue, and you should probably ask a new question. However, if you have installed this [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) in your project directory (instead of globally), you may want to try: **1)** `cd` to your project directory. **2)** Then run this command: `./node_modules/.bin/http-server`

Comment: That actually works. Thanks a lot! @RobC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the directory and check if the inputs are valid paths. It may be because the path is out of order.